# how to specify timeout when creating a connection to zookeeper server

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I have been using ZooKeeper for some time now in my development but one thing I don't seem to get is that there is no way (at least I couldn't figure it out) how to specify a timeout while creating a connection to a ZooKeeper server for example:

```
ZooKeeper zoo;
        final CountDownLatch connectedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        zoo = new ZooKeeper("localhost:2182", 5000, new Watcher() {

            public void process(WatchedEvent we) {
                if (we.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
                    connectedSignal.countDown();
                }
                if (we.getState() == KeeperState.Disconnected) {
                    connectedSignal.countDown();
                }
                if (we.getType() == Event.EventType.None) {
                    connectedSignal.countDown();
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("in watcher");
        connectedSignal.await();
```

Note that no timeout seems to occur if the ZooKeeper server is down and hence no exception is thrown and my code always keeps waiting for the countdown latch.  I have tried setting this property in zoo.cfg also but it doesn't takes any effect:

```
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=5000
```

Need help as to whether there is some way provided in java API for ZooKeeper to check if a successful connection cannot be created to a ZooKeeper server? Note, I know we can do it via executorservice and futures but I need a way provided in the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a ZooKeeper object is created, it will also create two threads: IO thread, and Event thread. The IO thread will do session maintenance such as reconnecting to ZooKeeper servers and maintaining heartbeat.

And in the above code, `5000` is the session timeout value, it works! If you enable logging, you will find heartbeat logs,

```
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid 0x...
```

and while disconnected

```
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x... for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect...`
```

And now, we need to know that Watch has some limitations

> When you disconnect from a server (for example, when the server fails), you will not get any watches until the connection is reestablished.

As we could not receive any watcher event while disconnected, the  `connectedSignal.await()` might be a little dangerous in practice. You could try use a timed-out version, `connectedSignal.await(5000)` instead, or you would wait until the connection recovery.

And if you want to monitor the connection to ZK server, you could spawn a separate thread, run `zoo.getState()` periodically to see the current state.

Comment: cheers your answer sorted it out for me and gave me the push in a direction i wasn't looking.dont forget to upvote the question though :-)